# User input asked continually in a loop c++

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop, cout, cin

I'm making a program that takes multiple student names and calculates a final grade based on grades entered in. The problem I'm having is that when it loops to the second student, it doesn't let me enter the grades, and I'm not sure why. Any suggestions?

```
#include <algorithm>                                                            
#include <iomanip>                                                              
#include <ios>                                                                  
#include <iostream>                                                             
#include <string>                                                               
#include <vector>                                                               

using std::cin;     using std::setprecision;                                    
using std::cout;    using std::string;                                          
using std::endl;    using std::streamsize;                                      
using std::sort;    using std::vector;

int main() {
     vector<string> names;                                                       
     vector<double> finals;                                                      
     typedef vector<double>::size_type vec_sz;                                   
     vec_sz sizeStud;                                                            
     string name;                                                                
     double sum, grade;                                                          
     int counter;                                                                

     cout<<"Please enter the student's names \"end-of-input\" to end:\t";        
     while(cin>>name&&name!="end-of-input") {                                    
         names.push_back(name);                                                  
     }                                                                           
     sizeStud = names.size();                                                    
     if(sizeStud == 0) {                                                         
         cout<<"No students entered! Please try again."<<endl;                   
         return 1;                                                               
     }                                                                           

     for(int i = 0; i < sizeStud; i++) {                                         
         sum=0;                                                                                            
         counter=0;                                                              
         cout<<"Please enter the grades for "<<names[i]                          
             <<" \"end-of-input\" to end:\t";                                    
         while(cin>>grade) {                                                     
             counter++;                                                          
             sum+=grade;                                                         
         }                                                                       
         if(counter==0) {                                                        
             cout<<"No grades entered! Please try again."<<endl;                 
         }                                                                       
         else {                                                                  
             cout<<endl;                                                         
             finals.push_back(sum/counter);                                      
         }                                                                       
     }                                                                           
     for(int i =0 ; i < sizeStud; i++) {                                         
         streamsize prec = cout.precision();                                     
         cout<<names[i]<<"'s final:\t\t"<<setprecision(4)                        
             <<finals[i]<<setprecision(prec)<<endl;                              
     }                                                                           

     return 0;              
}
```

Example input:

```
fred sally joe end-of-input
10 20 end-of-input
30 end-of-input
```

Sample output (from [ideone.com here](http://ideone.com/QLpwMR)):

```
Please enter the student's names "end-of-input" to end: Please enter the grades for fred "end-of-input" to end: 
Please enter the grades for sally "end-of-input" to end:    No grades entered! Please try again.
Please enter the grades for joe "end-of-input" to end:  No grades entered! Please try again.
fred's final:       15
sally's final:      1.719e-312
joe's final:        1.316e-312
```

Comment: Good starting point for using a decent debugger to step through your code.

Comment: Yes, use a debugger. Hint: while(cin>>grade)

Comment: Adding spaces around your operators would be a good idea (they don't take up any room in the executable and the time extending the build process is negligible).

Comment: Note: there are a lot of close votes, probably because the exact input hasn't been mentioned anywehere.  I'll edit in an illustration of the problem....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
while(cin>>grade)
```

Because `grade` is a `double`, if your input is "end-of-input" the while loop will exit but the `cin` stream will be set in an error state and further input will not be attempted (the next `for` loop iteration will reach `while(cin>>grade)` and fall through immediately).  You can use [`cin.clear()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) to clear the error state, and [`cin.ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore)`(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')` to consume the rest of the line's input.  Then input such as...

```
fred sally joe end-of-input
10 20 30 any-non-numeric-content
10 20 sally's scores
30 end-of-input
```

...will "work".